# Django filter by date like "201803"

Tags: python, django, rest, filter

Srry for my english. I try create some filter list like `?date=201803` - its meen get all data 2018 years 03 month. This is my model:

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(blank=False)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=256, blank=False)
```

This is my view:

```
class TestView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = TestSerializer
    queryset = TestModel.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('date',)
```

but if i can view some date if do like this:

`?date=2005-03-12T21:48:00Z`

field `date = models.DateTimeField(blank=False)` must be `DateTimeField`

How can do request like this: `?date=201803` ?

**UPD: 
this code return empty list**

```
permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = GlobalLogSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, )
    filter_fields = ('date', )

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = GlobalLog.objects.all()
        date = self.request.query_params.get('date', None)
        if date is not None:
            queryset = GlobalLog.objects.filter(date__year=2017, date__month=3)
        return queryset
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to split 201803 in to year and month.Then you can query it using below query

```
TestModel.objects.filter(date__year=2018,date__month=03)
```

Here is the [documentation link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#year).

Comment: please, check my update question. I dont know, but my code return empty list if i use filter

Comment: @nesalexy, your question says 201803, but your code is 201703. Is it correct?